# run function on complete of animation

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get a function to fire once this animation is complete. is this possible with jquery?

Here is my code

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$("body > .addAccountForm1").offset().top }, 'slow');
```

I want to fire this after it is complete

```
 $("body > .addAccountForm1").find(".acctSelectSchl").val(5);
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$("body > .addAccountForm1").offset().top }, 'slow', function(){
 $("body > .addAccountForm1").find(".acctSelectSchl").val(5);  
});
})
```

Answer (score 0):

$("selector").animate({},1000,function(){
// your call back function
});

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$("body > .addAccountForm1").offset().top }, 'slow',function(){
    $("body > .addAccountForm1").find(".acctSelectSchl").val(5);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, the 4th argument of animate is the complete handler (this is where you would put your code, or a call to another function to execute on completion).

From the jQuery documentation: .animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )

Please see http://api.jquery.com/animate/ for a list of examples and full documentation.